# sun misc.Base64 encoder cannot be resolved to a type in ecllipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin, sts

sun misc.Base64 encoder cannot be resolved to a type in eclipse.

I have tried few solutions like changing

Windows->Preferences->java->compiler->forbidden rule error To Warning

But nothing worked!!

Is there any way to fix this?.Instead of java.utils.Base64 ..

Comment: Why don't you want to use `java.util.Base64`? Classes in `sun.misc` may not exist in some JVMs.

Comment: Are you sure `sun.misc.Base64` actually exists in the JRE you're building against?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF

The class sun.misc.Base64 will give you errors if you have a JRE above 1.8. There can be two solutions-

1. As @dan1st suggested, use the class `java.util.Base64`
2. Downgrade to JRE 1.8

Comment: Thank you.Its worked.I just tried so many solutions but yours awesome.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem, it may help others.